# How do I load data (csv file or similar) into a page via script tag?

Tags: html, resources, loading

Is there a way to load a resource in HTML5 via script tag? The following syntax does not seem to work.

```
<script src="file.structure" type="application/structure"></script>
```

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok looks like there is no way, but I think it would be an interesting addition, to be able to register particular parsers of specific mime-types...

solutions:

- pure ajax
- jsonp